# Need Help for Optimizing MySQL query with few joins

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-optimization

Hello I have the follow sql query it works but it is kind of slow

```
SELECT 
    ep . *,
    t_u.sUsername AS sLockedBy,
    epi.sName,
    em.sName AS sManufacturerName,
    SUM(IF(eop.dInProduction IS NULL
            AND eop.dFromProduction IS NULL
            AND eop.dShipped IS NULL
            AND eop.nIsCancelled = 0
            AND eos.sStatusCode NOT IN ('Canceled' , 'Finished', 'Complete'),
        1,
        0)) AS nProductOrdered,
    SUM(IF(eop.dInProduction IS NOT NULL
            AND eop.dFromProduction IS NULL
            AND eop.dShipped IS NULL
            AND eop.nIsCancelled = 0
            AND eos.sStatusCode NOT IN ('Canceled' , 'Finished', 'Complete'),
        1,
        0)) AS nProductInProduction,
    SUM(IF(eop.dInProduction IS NOT NULL
            AND eop.dFromProduction IS NOT NULL
            AND eop.dShipped IS NULL
            AND eop.nIsCancelled = 0
            AND eos.sStatusCode NOT IN ('Canceled' , 'Finished', 'Complete'),
        1,
        0)) AS nProductFromProduction,
    SUM(IF(eop.dInProduction IS NULL
            AND eop.dFromProduction IS NULL
            AND eop.dShipped IS NULL
            AND eop.nIsCancelled = 0
            AND eos.sStatusCode NOT IN ('Canceled' , 'Finished', 'Complete'),
        1,
        0)) + ep.nInStock AS nStockCheck
FROM
    eshop3_products AS ep
        LEFT JOIN
    users AS t_u ON ep.nUserLockID = t_u.nUID
        AND t_u.nDeleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
    eshop3_products_i18n AS epi ON ep.nUID = epi.nProductID
        AND epi.nLangID = 1
        AND epi.nDeleted = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    eshop3_manufacturers AS em ON ep.nManufacturerID = em.nUID
        AND em.nDeleted = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    eshop3_order_products AS eop ON ep.nUID = eop.nProductID
        LEFT JOIN
    eshop3_orders AS eo ON eop.nOrderID = eo.nUID
        LEFT JOIN
    eshop3_order_statuses AS eos ON eo.nUID = eos.nOrderID
        AND eos.nUID = (SELECT 
            nUID
        FROM
            eshop3_order_statuses as eos
        WHERE
            eo.nUID = eos.nOrderID
        ORDER BY eos.nUID DESC
        LIMIT 1)
WHERE
    (ep.nDeleted = 0)
GROUP BY ep.nUID
ORDER BY ep.sStoreCode ASC
```

The Product Table has total 462 rows,

The Order Statuses Tables has total 17 154 rows

The execution time of the query is 1.5 secs which I think it is slow.

I use the INNER SELECT in the ON clause to get the last status for the given order, and here I think there is something wrong.

WHen I remove the order statuses table from the whole query the execution time is several times faster 0.152 secs

Could you give me some advice how can I optimize the query I have

Here you go the sql with explain

[image]

```
id  select_type        table type   possible_keys    key      key_len ref                            rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY            epi   ALL    nProductID                                                        408  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY            ep    eq_ref PRIMARY,nUID     PRIMARY        4 dragoni_zfms.epi.nProductID       1  Using where
1   PRIMARY            em    eq_ref PRIMARY          PRIMARY        4 dragoni_zfms.ep.nManufacturerID   1 
1   PRIMARY            t_u   eq_ref PRIMARY          PRIMARY        4 dragoni_zfms.ep.nUserLockID       1 
1   PRIMARY            eop   ref    id_productid     id_productid   5 dragoni_zfms.ep.nUID             13 
1   PRIMARY            eo    eq_ref PRIMARY          PRIMARY        4 dragoni_zfms.eop.nOrderID         1  Using index
1   PRIMARY            eos   eq_ref PRIMARY,nOrderID PRIMARY        4 func                              1  
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY eos   ref    nOrderID         nOrderID       4 dragoni_zfms.eo.nUID              1  Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

Comment: Try changing that sub select into a join.  Maybe something with the group by and selecting MAX will get similar results as opposed to order by DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Can you provide the EXPLAIN as text rather than a picture.

Comment: Please show the definition of your `order_statuses` table.

Comment: the very same alias (eos) is used to identify different items (the same table actually but is called twice in different context). maybe this is not an issue but a different name would be helpful when debugging.

Comment: @Strawberry I have provided the explain as text, can you check it out

Comment: @OllieJones What do you mean by definition of order_statuses table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it is easier to perform some operations not using mysql but using php.
I have seen in my practice cases when you win time. Please, try to divide a complex query into several simple queries. Then perform the necessary filtering using php scripts.
Hope it helps.
Thanks!